# Time complexity of this algorithm using Big-O notation

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I have to find the time complexity of the pseudocode I have created and specify it using the Big-O notation. The problem is that I don't know how to calculate it when I have an if-statement inside nested for-loops. 
Here is my pseudocode, what is in brackets is the number of operations:

```
Algorithm largestProduct(A)
  Input array A
  Output largest product value of two elements in array A, the values and their indices
  index1 ← 0                                          (1)
  index2 ← 0                                          (1)
  n ← A length                                        (1)
  max ← 0                                             (1)
  for i ← 0 to n-1 do                                 (n)
    for j ← i + 1 to n do                             (n^2)
      if max < A[ i ] * A[ j ] then                   (?)
        max ← A[ i ] * A[ j ]
        index1 ← i
        index2 ← j
  return max, A[index1], index1, A[index2], index2
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the operations inside the `if` statement and its condition do not affect the number of the iterations and they are single operations (constant), then you can consider the `if` statement as an `O(1)`.

It is true that the nested `for` loops do `O(n^2)` iterations, therefore, there are constant amount of operations running `O(n^2)` times, makes it `O(n^2)*O(1)=O(n^2)` overall.